# Continuous function positive at a point is positive in a neighborhood of that point

Tags: analysis, continuity

Pretty much the problem asks if a function is continuous at the point $c$ and $f(c) > 0$ then there exists a $d > 0$ such that $\forall x$, $f(x) > 0$ with $|x-c| < d$.

I can understand what the problem means. That if a function is positive at a point then there is another point that's really close that'll also be positive. I can not prove this in a formal way though. I've tried using the intermediate value theorem and I do not know hot to implement it. Any ideas?

Comment: When is a function called continuous?

Comment: $\ldots$ *if a function is positive at a point then there is another point that's really close that'll also be positive.* For what it's worth, being positive in a neighborhood of a point is a much stronger condition than being able to find another point really close where the function is positive. (Of course, I assume you mean arbitrarily close, and thus a sequence of such nearby points converging to the given point). Consider the function that is equal to $1$ for $x \in \{0, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \ldots \}$ and equal to $0$ for every other real value of $x.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will follow from the definition of continuity applied to the point $x=c$. In particular, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that for any $\epsilon > 0$:

$|f(c) - f(x)| < \epsilon \, \, \, \, \mbox{if} \, \, \, \, |x-c| < \delta$.

This is equivalent to saying that $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $f(c)$:

$f(x) \in (f(c) - \epsilon, f(c) + \epsilon)\, \, \, \, \mbox{if} \, \, \, \, |x-c| < \delta$.

So that clearly $f(x) > f(c) -\epsilon$. Thus, simply choose any value for $\epsilon$ for which $0<\epsilon < f(c)$ (which we can do because $f(c)$ is positive by assumption). Thus, $\exists \delta$

$f(x) > f(c) - \epsilon > 0 \, \, \, \, \mbox{if} \, \, \, \, |x-c| < \delta$.

Comment: I think you mean "such that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$"

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the definition of continuity.

$f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

If $f$ is continuous, then what does continuity imply when $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < f(x_0)$?

Comment: that the limit as x approaches x_0 of f(x) = f(x_0)?

Comment: $-f(x_0) < f(x) - f(x_0) < f(x_0)$. So you have that $f(x) > 0$. Now you just need to use the definition of continuity to show the existence of the $\delta$.