# Let $f$ continuous and $A$ dense in $D$. Prove is $f(x)=0\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=0\forall x\in D$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Hi i need help with this exercise.

Exercise:
Let $f$ continuous and $A$ dense in $D$. Prove is $f(x)=0\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=0\forall x\in D$

I try this:

Suppose exist $x\in D$ such that$f(x)\neq0$. As $f$ is continuous in $D$ and $A$ is dense in $D$ then It does not happen that $f(x)=0\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=0\forall x\in A$ then $f(x)=0\forall x\in D$.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the fact that if a continous function $f$ is not zero at $x\in D$, say $f(x) > 0$, then $$\exists r: f(x+\delta) > 0~\forall \delta \in [-r,r].$$
It comes straightforwardly rom the definition of continuity.

Then it remains to note that as $A$ is dense in $D$, then it is dense in $D\cap[x-r,x+r]$. So

$$\exists a\in A\cap D\cap[x-r,x+r]$$

In this point $f(a)$ should be positive according to our reasonings. Cotradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, why you take $f(x+\delta) > 0~\forall \delta \in [-r,r]$. In other words why that $f(x+\delta)$??

Comment: @Bvss12, you mean, why is this true?

Comment: Yes, more explicit please.

Comment: @Bvss12, take a look at the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063109/continuous-function-positive-at-a-point-is-positive-in-a-neighborhood-of-that-po

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0 \in D$ and let $(x_n) $ be a sequence in $A$ such that $x_n \to x_0$.

$f$ is continuous , hence $f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$. Since $f(x_n)=0$ for alle $n$, we get $f(x_0)=0$

Comment: Very simply fred, thanks. Excellent work.